# how do you add extra pages to .net xml documentation?

Tags: .net, xml-documentation

using tools like NDoc or Sandcastle you can generate documentation from .Net code xml documentation.

So my question: How can I easily add additional pages?

For example, I would like to add a "Vocabulary" or an "about" page at the top level of the docs.

using tools like SandCastle, I know you can add documentation of Namespaces using the "NamespaceDoc" class,  which is great, but isn't providing the flexibilty i'd like.

Additionally, it would be great if these pages were linkable via xml docs (ex: " for more info") but as I don't know even a basic way of inserting pages, this may be too much to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no easy way,  have to use complex doc generators unfortunately.  piece of crap :(